# TypeError: The view function for 'connector' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt  # import client library
import time
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def connector():
    def on_log(client, userdata, buf):  # Call back function
        print('log: ' + buf)

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):  # Call back function
        if rc == 0:
            print('Connected successfully')
        else:
            print('Bad connection. Code: ' + str(rc))

    def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):  # Call back function
        print('Disconnected result code ' + str(rc))

    def on_message(client, userdata, message):
        print("received message: ", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
        print('message topic=', message.topic)

        data = {
            "reading": message.payload
        }
        requests.post(data)

    broker_address = "----------"

    client = mqtt.Client("python2")
    print('Connecting to broker ... ', broker_address)
    client.connect(broker_address)

    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_log = on_log
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

    client.loop_start()  # for proccessing the callback functions

    client.subscribe("RTA/rooms")
    client.on_message = on_message

    time.sleep(4)
    client.loop_stop()


if __name__ == '_main_':
    app.run()
```

How i can resolve this ... ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error and the input you used to get the error.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or something? Could you tell us more about what you are trying to do or what you are expecting? If you have some time, please also consider giving this short manual a quick read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Especially the "Introduce the problem before you post any code" part.

Comment: I think your connect function should return something so it can view in the route. try adding a dummy return with string to see if that solves the issue

Comment: As I can only guess what you are trying to do, one thing that looks off is that you seem to try to launch some kind of long-running process within the scope of a request. That is not a good idea. HTTP requests are meant to be answered with an immediate answer. You probably want to launch whatever the mqtt client is outside of the request scope and only control the previously created client through web requests.

Comment: I have service with the information about academy lessons, i need this information what i see in MQTT, send in my pycharm terminal, because then i want this information send to webservce.

Problem what i see is in def on_message funktion.